# Will a tortoise moving $1$ unit at a time around a circle meet a hare moving $2$ units at a time?

Tags: logic

Consider a circle with $100$ points numbered $1,2,3,4,\dotsc,99,100$. Now there is a tortoise at the point numbered $1$ and a hare at point numbered $2$.  Both can only move in clockwise direction, and only on numbered points.  The tortoise moves **one** point at time e.g., from $1$ to $2$, from $2$ to $3$, and so on. The hare moves **two** points at a time e.g., from $2$ to $4$, from $4$ to $6$ and so on. They start moving and move at the same time i.e, when the tortoise moves from $1$ to $2$, then hare also moves from $2$ to $4$. They continue to move like this until they meet at some point. Either find the point at which they meet, or if they do not meet at some point, explain why.

The seems to be very easy but I just can't figure out how proceed though I know for them to meet at a point hare must be at some point x-1 if tortoise is at some point x only then they will meet at point x+1 in next turn any help would be appreciated..

Comment: What're your thoughts?

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Comment: After moving the hare and the tortoise on the circle by 1 and 2 moves each, rotate the circle counter clockwise one unit with the animals fixed to it. It will just seem like the hare moved one unit around the circle and the tortoise did not. The unit distance from hare to tortoise equals units of time it would take to catch it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can think of moving around the 100 points in the circle as the set $\mathbb{Z}/100\mathbb{Z}$, that is the integers modulo $100$. So for example, when the tortoise has moved 154 times from it's starting position, it's really just 54 points from the start, i.e. at 55.

The way I approach is as follows: the hare moves twice as fast as the tortoise, and starts 1 spot ahead of it. If the tortoise has taken $n$ steps, then the hare has taken $2n+1$ steps, both $\mod 100$. So asking when the hare and tortoise meet is equivalent to asking, when is the following true:
$$
2n+1 \equiv n \mod 100.
$$
Evidently, $n=99$ is the first occurrence (and so they meet at point 100).

Comment: Your formula fails if tortoise is at point 3 then clearly hare is at point 6 but your formula for position of hare 2n+1(mod 100) gives position 7

Comment: @BhashkarYadav I am thinking of $\mathbb{Z}/100\mathbb{Z}$ as the points $\{0,1,2,3,\dots,99\}$, which we can think of as how many steps each animal has taken. So when the tortoise as taken $0$ steps, the hare is $2(0) + 1 = 1$ step ahead. And, after 99 steps, they meet (and 99 steps is the point 100).

Comment: @BhashkarYadav yes you are right, I meant how many steps they have taken. I will edit the answer.

Comment: Thanks, Can you also please solve this problem if hare is at point 24 and tortoise is at point 1?? I am finding it difficult

Comment: Absolutely. And I thought of a more intuitive way to think about the problem. As a function of time $t$, which is an integer in this case, the position of the tortoise is $t + 1$, while in (the problem you just posed) the position of the hare is $2t + 24$, both modulo $100$. So for what $t$ are these equal? Solve $2t + 24 \equiv t + 1 \mod 100$.

Comment: (Answer: $t = 77$, so they will meet at position $78$)

Answer (score 2):

If both make one reverse move, they would align at point $100$. We can call that move $-1$.

As the hare moves twice as fast as the tortoise, the hare completes two laps for every one that the tortoise completes. Thus they meet at point $100$ every time the tortoise completes a lap, or every hundred moves.

That is, they align at moves $-1$, $99$, $199$, ...

Comment: what if hare is at point 23 and tortoise is at initial point 1